# Add "- Please Select -" to a required CCK field

Tags: entities

In Drupal 6, by default, a required CCK field will display the first allowed value.
I want it displays "- Please Select -": Is there an easy way to do this?

I do not want to save "- Please Select -" in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the key|label format for allowed values:

```
|-Please Select -
1|option1
2|option2
3|option3
```

By making the key for "-Please Select -" an empty string, the form can't be submitted with this value.

Comment: This should work if the field is required.

Comment: This worked amazingly!

Answer (score 0):

In the list of options of *global settings* of field you can put in first place the option - Please Select - :

-Please Select -
option1
option2
option3

Save the field.

After in the *field settings* you choose - Please Select - in default value of the field.

Finally you save the configuration of field.

Comment: I thought of this, however I do not want - Please Select - be saved to the database

Answer (score 0):

seems like [AHAH](http://drupal.org/node/348475) can do the job to populate select list or add items: [AHAH - populating a select (list) with a select (drop-down)](http://drupal.org/node/411074).

Answer (score 0):

Put your field as not required and then in a [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) check that the user has effectively selected a value:

```php
function custom_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'validate') {
      if ($node->field_select[0]['value'] == '') {
        form_set_error('field_select', t('Please select a value.'));
      }
  }
}
```